# Documents required for a newborn baby traveling to India from UK

Tags: united-kingdom, indian-citizens

We are currently on UK Tier 2 general leave to remain and expecting a baby in March 2021 and then we want to travel to India urgently:

1. What documents would we need for the newborn baby to travel please as in Passport? Visa?
2. How to sort these out if we need it urgently?
3. Would the newborn would be British citizen by default

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> What documents would we need for the newborn baby to travel?

An Indian passport.

> Would the newborn would be British citizen?

No.  A child born in the UK is a British citizen if one or both parents is "permanently settled."  In other words, the child would be a British citizen if one of you either has ILR or right of abode.  Since your leave to remain is not indefinite, your child will not be a British citizen.

Comment: Thanks David. So that means the baby doesn't need any visa to travel to India isn't it? Just Indian passport is required. Is there any provision of Emergency travel document as well to travel to India as I read sorting passport would take time

Comment: @Anshul a visa is for noncitizens.  Your child will be an Indian citizen so will not need, and will not be able to get, a visa to travel to India.  I'm afraid I don't know about emergency travel.